# What happens to event listener handler context when a function is being invoked inside it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method that spawn a child process, which has event listeners and it's handlers inside it.

My question are:

1. What will happen to method context(memory) when I re-invoke the method inside an event handler inside it?
2. Will garbage collection clear the method context or will it still remain in memory until the entire application exist

   ```
   import { spawn } from 'child_process';
   class SomeThing {
   initChildProcess() {
     const childProcess = spawn('go', [ 'run', 'awesome.go' ])
     // what will happen to this context
     // will garbage collector clear it?
     childProcess.once('close', () => {
       // when I re-invoked it inside this event handler?
       this.initChildProcess()
     })
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you show, as soon as your internal call to `this.initChildProcess()` returns (which will be quickly because `spawn()` is asynchronous), then your original call to `initChildProcess()` is done and the `childProcess` object from that call will be in a closed state and with no further event listeners on it (or events that can happen) so it will be eligible for garbage collection.

> What will happen to method context(memory) when I re-invoke the method inside an event handler inside it?

See above for conditions for garbage collection.  With what you show, it will be garbage collected.  The reinvoke does not have any connection to the context associated with the original invocation.

> Will garbage collection clear the method context or will it still remain in memory until the entire application exist

It will clear it.  The second invocation of `spawn()` has no code reference to the first so the first will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the native code behind the first `spawn()` is done or as soon as you have no more event listeners on the first `childProcess` object.  That will make the `childProcess` object unreachable by any code and therefore eligible for garbage collection.